# Simple map-builder for x-z plane

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xna

I'm working on a simple first person 3D game in XNA. I have gotten to the point where I can place walls in my world, move arround with a propper first person camera and check collision between the walls and the camera.

I have done myself the favor of creating some wall-"drawing" functions that makes it fairly easy to place walls (simply a start and end position), but I still find it horribly annoying to place one by one wall, coordinate by coordinate, when my goal is to create labyrinths ;)

All I need to place a wall is 2 vertexes, a start and an end position. They can even be in 2D, as I only need the X and Z position. I have fixed height for walls.

I have been searching a little for a program that would let me plot coordinates and export as XML or some other format I can load in XNA/C#. If I could simply get two and two coordinates out from xml, that I plot in a program, building maps would be unbelievably much easier!

Does anyone know of something like this I could use? It could be as simple as a sheet that I set the size of (lets say 5000x5000px), then I place two points on the sheet (they would represent two x,y positions) and link them together. Then I could read the two points from whatever output format in my program and create the walls.

I would go ahead and make something myself, but sadly I am horribly limited by time thanks to exams and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you think about using SVG consisting from straight lines instead of bitmap?
You can then write simple content pipeline extension which parse the SVG to precomputed vertex/index buffer data. Since you need just lines and not any fluffy SVG stuff, the
parser should not get so hard and expensive.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SVG. My main limitation is that I have very little time (this is in fact a project for uni that I'm going to deliver, and I'v probably taken a leap of faith hoping I'll manage to do it in 3D, as we were adviced not to due to time limitatation ;), and I'm afraid of beginnning on something im not familiar with. I'm guessing it will be hard finding something like that I described in OP, so I'll just have to live with plotting coordinates manually, alternatively finish the other stuff I need and then start looking for something if I have time in the end.

Comment: It is basically the XML you wanted. For line segments, you should care about line tag only. For editing, you can use Inkscape. Here is the SVG specification and example for lines [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#LineElement). The parser will be really short (guess about 50 lines) so it is definitely worth it!

Comment: Allright, thanks for the tips then! I will take a look in a few hours probably. Working on character animation right now.

Comment: It does seem like a good solution, but so far it proves to require more fiddling then I first expected. First and foremost Im having trouble finding a svg "paint" program that's not stupidly advanced and allows me to set the size of the image im drawing at customly. Secondly importing xml/svg in XNA context seems more difficult than I first thought. I have never used XML in C#/XNA, only in c++. I will have to put this aside for a while now and pick it up again later if I get the time. If you happen to have know of any tutorials on loading SVG in XNA meanwhile that would be great, thank anyway!

Comment: I recently found Library called Algae. It is one of many XNA reimplementations with OpenGl. But it contains also simple SVG parser reading path tags from svg. You could probably reuse it simply.